# Disks in Flat Embeddings of Graphs in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, embeddings

Robertson, Seymour and Thomas proved that any linkless graph $G$ has a flat embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (see for example [A survey of linkless embeddings](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/linklsurvey.pdf)). An embedding of $G$ is flat if for any cycle $C$ in $G$ there is a disk that is bounded by $C$ such that it is not crossed by any of the edges of $G$. Throughout this paper they are talking about piece-wise linear embeddings of graphs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but they do not say whether the disks are also embedded piece-wise linearly or not).

Now my question is about the disks in such flat embeddings: Can I assume that these disks are also embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ piece-wise linearly?

Comment: Yes, they are referring to PL embedded graphs and disks. In any case, if one of the disks were embedded in some nasty way (like a piece of an Alexander Horned sphere), then Dehn's lemma implies that there is an embedded PL disk.

Comment: Let $d$ be the disk that is implied by Dehn's lemma. Then there is no guarantee that $d$ is not crossed by the edges of the graph. Is there? Because if $d$ is crossed by the edges of the graph then I cannot replace the original disk with $d$ to obtain a flat embedding.

Comment: Moreover, Dehn's lemma is useful if the disks are embedded piecewise linearly.

Comment: I meant to apply Dehn's lemma in the complement of the graph, so that the embedded disk it produces would still not cross the graph (in its interior). Technically, you need to thicken the graph up to a handlebody first, and work in a manifold with boundary in the complement of this handlebody  to apply Dehn's lemma.